# Is Interface comes in inheritance chain or not?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

There are two type of statements on internet about `Interface`, that is

Statement A

> Interfaces do not come in inheriting chain.

other statement B

> [Interfaces can inherit other interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

These two are contradicting statements.

Please tell me which one is right?

Comment: Interfaces will show up in their own inheriting chains, but they won't show up in the inheritance chain of any classes that implement them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both true, sort of.

Statement A: Interfaces don't strictly inherit.  If you have a class that implements an interface, and you say

```
base.
```

You won't see members of the interface.

Statement B: This would read better as "Interfaces can *implement* other interfaces".  You can have an implementation chain; but they're not really inheriting.

Comment: I agree with you this confusion comes due to word `Inheritance`, it should be `implement`.

Comment: @jams: Interfaces don't really "implement" anything.  One can argue about whether the term "inherit" is completely appropriate, but it seems less inaccurate than "implement".  The key point is that "class1:class2", "class:interface", and "interface1:interface2" describe three fundamentally different kinds of relationships.  If one is going to use two terms to describe the three kinds of relationships, my preference would be to say that within the world of classes, "inherit" means one thing; within the world of interfaces, it means another.  It is inapplicable when crossing between worlds.

Answer (score 5):

Interfaces can inherit other interfaces, try it and you'll see that it works.

Comment: Yes. Also note that generally you can trust information on MSDN over other sources.

Comment: Statement A doesn't even make sense. Where did you read it and what context was it written in?

Comment: @Jamie Dixon : As it is available on so many places. Here one of them http://www.coolinterview.com/interview/9108/

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what is meant by the first statement.  It is rather vague.

Answer (score 2):

Both statements are correct.

The second statement is correct. InterfaceA: InterfaceB is perfectly fine and classes implementing InterfaceA must also inherit InterfaceB.

What is meant by "Interfaces do not come in inheriting chain" means that if DerivedClass : BaseClass, InterfaceA, you can access BaseClass members from DerivedClass by using base.BaseClassMethod, while you cannot call base.InterfaceAMethod in the same way because interfaces are not part of the inheritance chain. Rather, their members are accessible via polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

They are both true, because they are both possible with C#. BUT,
as we write clean code and [program to an interface instead of an implementation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232359/understanding-programming-to-an-interface):

- We don't want to [get surprised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) with the interface-chains.
- And, we follow the [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Consider this,

```
interface IFileRepository : IDisposable { ... }
```

This says, whomever implements the `IFileRepository`, MUST implement the `IDisposable`. But, I can write a FileRepository, which might not need to dispose any resource. Or another example during unit-testing that I write a `FileRepository`-**Stub** for a class which uses it as dependency, but doesn't invoke `Dispose()` at all, at least in the method I test. And yet, I have to implement `IDisposable`.

Clean-design should not dictate such implementation. Concrete implementations should know what to provide.

```
class FileRespository : IFileRepository , IDisposable { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET world, interfaces can absolutely inherit other interfaces.  Any implementing class is then expected to implement all methods and properties of all the interfaces it inherits.

If there is a naming contradiction, the implementing class has to use [explicit interface implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).