# Should my library implement both IDisposable and IAsyncDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

there is already a [similar question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074767/should-class-implement-both-iasyncdisposable-and-idisposable) but my question is about a class exposed to the client.

```cs
public class MyClass : IAsyncDisposable {
  public ValueTask DisposeAsync() => DoAsyncStuff();
}
```

The dispose of this class is asynchronous and an implementation of `IDisposable` would block the thread.

```cs
public void Dispose() => DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

If `IDisposable` is implemented on the class and the user is in a synchronous context so they use the `using` statement: `using (var c = new MyClass()) {}`, that would block the thread in the back of the user and I think that's very bad. Instead, I would prefer not to implement `IDisposable` and force the user to use this explicit form:

```cs
MyClass c;
try { c = new MyClass(); }
finally { c.DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }
```

That's more verbose but at least the user won't have bad surprise.

I didn't included code sample of my library because it's a general question. So what do you think about it and have you ever experienced issues when the `Dispose` method was waiting synchronously on a `Task` behind your back?

Comment: I think if you can't do a proper non-blocking synchronous disposal, don't implement `IDisposable`. Your blocking `Dispose` method would have the potential to deadlock the user's code, and it's bad to do that to them without them realising the risk

Comment: Thanks. Is your answer still applicable pre-netcoreapp3.0? By that I mean if `IAsyncDisposable` didn't exist (for instance in a netcoreapp2.2), would you still not implement a blocking `IDisposable`?

Comment: That gets hard. I would definitely have some sort of async shutdown method which did the necessary, and which must be called. I've gone the way of a blocking Dispose method (that should never actually be blocking in practice if someone calls the proper shutdown method first), and also the way of having Dispose throw if it wasn't shut down (bad voodoo, but hey, compromises), and just having Dispose do badish things if it wasn't properly shut down. There's no "best" answer, they're all a bit bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound, and in this scenario: yes, I'd only implement `IAsyncDisposable`.

As for callers in a sync context: even that explicit form should be actively discouraged. The reality is that async is infectious, and it is pretty normal for code that touches async components to also have to be async. So forcing the caller to use an async context is entirely reasonable, IMO.